# How can I read data from AWS Aurora using API gateway and Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am using AWS Aurora database and created **read replica** for it. I have inserted some data in that database using **MYSQL workbench**. Now I want to **retrieve that data when i hit the API**. I want to put that data into another DynamoDB database. Can anyone suggest me the way to achieve this as I am new to AWS Aurora.

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far and which error you got.  Which language you are using, etc

Comment: I have created an Aurora MYSQL database and also created read replica for it. Also created DynamoDB which is working fine. Now i'm facing problem while retrieving data from Aurora MYSQL as i am new to Aurora. Can u please  guide me to retrieve data from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aurora is compatible to MYSQL so reading from Aurora is same as reading from MYSQL.